# Meteor check package: correct type of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have some question regarding the `check()` function of meteor. If I understand it correctly, I should do a check for every parameter of a function - like this:

```
capitalizeFirstLetter = function(string) {
    check(string, String);
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
};
```

How do I check for a floating number, which also could have no decimals? Right now I do it like this:

```
round = function(value, decimals) {
    check(value, Number);
    check(decimals, Number);
    return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
};
```

In another case I'm getting position values of a given JQuery-DOM-element. Is this technically just a string?

```
getPosition = function(element) {
    check(element, String);
    var pos = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { x: pos.left, y: pos.top };
};
```

Comment: The jQuery element should be Object.

Comment: @StephenWoods: That's not working